# Jest unit test "Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute"

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular10, angular-unit-test

I'm doing some simple components for my "dynamic-ish" automated form creator and I've just made a component for dropdown:

```html
<div>
  <select [name]="propertyName" [formControl]="customControl" [id]="propertyName">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Code is also bare simple:

```js
export class DropdownComponent {
  @Input() public customControl: AbstractControl;
  @Input() public propertyName: string;
  @Input() public options: any[];
}
```

Now when I run jest to test this component (which test is created by ng cli, so default, I only added ReactiveFormsModule as an import) it fails with the component creation.

```
  × should create (363 ms)

  ● DropdownComponent › should create

    Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
      at _throwError (../packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts:150:9)
      at setUpControl (../packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts:37:19)
      at ...
```

Versions:
Angular: 10.1.6
Jest: 26.6.3
Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Node: 14.4.0
OS: win32 x64

Comment: a better solution would be to implement ControlValueAccessor instead of passing form controls to input bindings

Answer (score 2):

Since google gave me 10 results (all misleading or impossible), I tried adding/removing parts of the code, came out that customControl needs to be initialized with a value despite it will receive a formcontrol from the outside (as being @Input). This is not a problem with `<input>` tags but is a problem with `<select>` tags!

```js
  @Input() public customControl: AbstractControl = new FormControl('');
```